# JQuery filtering a website onClick to remove certain divs or sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a blog style website that I've placed a dropdown button at top of for the purpose of filtering the content. Each blog post will reside in section tags.

When user clicks on menu item it will trigger click event. I'm trying to save the href which the code seems to do fine.

Then i was hoping to iterate each a tag with the class of "label".
With each one that is found it should check the text and compare to value from dropdown box. If it matches keep the content. If not detach it. I thought detach was the best method since I would need to put it back on refresh and/or if user clicks on another selection in the dropdown.

Here's what I tried:

```
<div class="container blog-content">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="sortMenu" data-toggle="dropdown">Sort By:
     <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="sortMenu">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="sortmenuitem" id="Adventure">Adventure</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="sortmenuitem" id="Food">Food</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="sortmenuitem" id="Nature">Nature</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="sortmenuitem" id="Sites">Sites</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 blog-main">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <section class="blog-post">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <img src="myimage.jpg" class="img-responsive" />
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="blog-post-meta">
                  <span class="label label-light label-danger">Adventure</span>
                  <p class="blog-post-date pull-right">January 1, 2016</p>
                </div>
              <div class="blog-post-content">
                  <a href="post-image.html">
                    <h2 class="blog-post-title">Blog Title 1</h2>
                  </a>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-info" href="post-image.html">Read more</a>
                  <a class="blog-post-share pull-right" href="#">
                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE80D;</i>
                  </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          </section>
       <!-- /.blog-post -->
          <section class="blog-post">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="blog-post-meta">
                  <span class="label label-light label-info">Food</span>
                  <p class="blog-post-date pull-right">January 1, 2016</p>
                </div>
                <div class="blog-post-content">
                  <a href="post-image.html">
                    <h2 class="blog-post-title">Blog Title 2</h2>
                  </a>
                  <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</p>
                  <a class="btn btn-info" href="post-image.html">Read more</a>
                  <a class="blog-post-share pull-right" href="#">
                    <i class="material-icons">&#xE80D;</i>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
    <!-- /.blog-post -->
```

JQuery:

```
      <script>
        $("a[role='sortmenuitem']").bind("click", function() {
            var value = $(this).attr( 'id' );
            $("a.label").each(function() {
              if (this.text('value')) {
                this.replace();
              }
              else {
                this.detach();
              }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

If there is a better approach all together, I am all ears.
I thought about giving each blog section a class matching its category, and then using CSS to hide the element. If I am in the right ballpark please let me know.

Furthermore, once we hide the section not matching the dropdown menu item that is selected I'd need to put it back if another element is selected.

I am new (obviously) to JQuery. Any "dumbed down" explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to hide/show the blog-post according to the current dropdown selection.

For the first, you need to change this line:

```
$("a.label")
```

to:

```
$(".blog-post .label")
```

because the label is associated to the span element under the blog-post section.

In order to test a value against a text you need to change this line:

```
this.text('value')
```

with:

```
$(this).text()
```

In order to hide/show the section inside the each loop you have to search for the closest blog-post parent section.

I added e.preventDefault() inside the click to stop navigation.

Moreover, as reported in the comment (***Khalid T***), instead to use [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) you have to use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) because its usage is deprecated.

So the snippet is:

```js
$("a[role='sortmenuitem']").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var value = $(this).attr( 'href' );
  $(".blog-post .label").each(function() {
    $(this).closest('.blog-post').toggle($(this).text() == value);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container blog-content">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="sortMenu" data-toggle="dropdown">Sort By:
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="sortMenu">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="sortmenuitem" href="Adventure">Adventure</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="sortmenuitem" href="Food">Food</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="sortmenuitem" href="Nature">Nature</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="sortmenuitem" href="Sites">Sites</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 blog-main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <section class="blog-post">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <img src="myimage.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>

                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="blog-post-meta">
                                    <span class="label label-light label-danger">Adventure</span>

                                    <p class="blog-post-date pull-right">January 1, 2016</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog-post-content">
                                    <a href="post-image.html">
                                        <h2 class="blog-post-title">Blog Title 1</h2>
                                    </a>

                                    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="post-image.html">Read more</a>
                                    <a class="blog-post-share pull-right" href="#">
                                        <i class="material-icons">&#xE80D;</i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                    <!-- /.blog-post -->
                    <section class="blog-post">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="blog-post-meta">
                                    <span class="label label-light label-info">Food</span>

                                    <p class="blog-post-date pull-right">January 1, 2016</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog-post-content">
                                    <a href="post-image.html">
                                        <h2 class="blog-post-title">Blog Title 2</h2>
                                    </a>

                                    <p>Lorem ipsum blah blah blah</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="post-image.html">Read more</a>
                                    <a class="blog-post-share pull-right" href="#">
                                        <i class="material-icons">&#xE80D;</i>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `.bind()` has been deprecated as of jQuery 3.0 and superseded by the `.on()`. So, its use is discouraged.

Comment: @gaetanoM That works great! Thank you for your time!!! Thanks for the explanations. It seems I was in the ball park. Vaguely, at most lol. I appeared that mostly syntax issues and one for not picking a better selector. It made sense as I read it. This is practically my first solo try at adding JQuery functionality. I've much more practice to do. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: @KhalidT. Thanks for the info on .bind() being deprecated. This added worth to the answer. Thank you kindly for the input.